# Power BI desktop does not detect RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, powerbi

I need to test R visualisation in Power BI. I want to connect Power BI to RStudio which is installed in my desktop.

Power BI detect without any issue the R home directory. But it is not the case for identifying RStudio. 
I also tried to select the RStudio .exe with "other" option, but nothing happen and the .exe is not taken into account.

[image]

Here is the source I use to try to solve my problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-r-ide

Does anyone have a solution, please ?

Best regards.

Comment: Works for me. Which version of R Studio have you installed? I'm using 1.1.383 which I should update at some point

Comment: I have not update RStudio for a while too. The version I am using is 1.1.442. I will try to update to see if something happen, thanks.

Comment: That's newer than mine. Did you install it in a non-default location perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I have installed it in a non-default location. I have now reinstall a newer version of RStudio leaving the default location, and it is working ! Thank you very much !